# Python instance string in a list

Tags: python, class

I have a simple class in python that has a `__str__()` function. Like this:

```
class Foo(object):
   def __init__():
       self.name = 'something'

   def __str__():
       return self.name
```

My real class does more than that, but this is an example.

So then I do this:

```
a = Foo()
b = Foo()

print a
print b
print [a,b]
```

Except this prints:

```
something
something
[<Foo object at HexString>,<Foo object at HexString>]
```

Why is the printed version in the list not printing the str name of the instance and is there an easy way to get it to?

I've tried to see if `__unicode__` is different and it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a `__repr__` method as well:

```
class Foo(object):
   def __repr__(self):
       return str(self)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) about the difference between `__str__` and `__repr__`.

Note also that you're missing the `self` arguments to the methods in your sample code ;-)

Comment: oops. I was typing that out by hand and just forgot them. The real code is correct.

Comment: Note that the default implementation of `__str__()` simply calls `__repr__()`, so if you want both to do the same, you only need to define `__repr__()`.

Answer (score 3):

The string representation of the list actually calls `__repr__()` on every item -- so just overwrite that method.